# How to split collection into arrays by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split

I have the following models

```
class BackupJob
  has_many :backup_controls

  def controls_for_date(date)
    return self.backup_controls.where("control_date > ?", date.beginning_of_day).where("control_date < ?", date.end_of_day)
  end
end

class BackupControl
  attr_accessible :status, :control_date

end
```

I want to get a collection of BackupControls on a certain date, and split these into different arrays, one for each status.

```
controls = backup_job.controls_for_date(date)
controls.sort{|x,y| x.backup_control_status <=> y.backup_control_status}
```

What is the best way to split my collection into separate arrays, one for each status?

Comment: `sort_by` + `group_by`

Comment: Your conditions will return all records where the control_date is on or after the given date, rather than on the given date. If it's a date field (as opposed to a datetime) you can just test if it's equal.

Comment: Your class name is pluralised, which goes against convention.

Comment: @MaxWilliams The query searches for a control_date larger than the beginning of the given date and smaller than the end of the given date, so yes it DOES return records of the correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sergio said, if you want a sorted collecion of BackupControls you should first sort it by control_date and after that group it by status. Something like that:

```ruby
controls = backup_job.controls_for_date(date).sort_by(&:control_date).group_by(&:status)
```

That would give you a Hash which the keys are the statuses and the values are arrays of BackupControls.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), passing in `&:backup_control_status`.